Why doesn't template argument deduction work with brace-enclosed initializer list?
There're a couple of questions that mention the problem [this, this]. But I'm more interested in the reason why that doesn't work.
Consider this example. The original intent should be self-explanatory.
template <typename T>
constexpr auto mem_vars = [] { static_assert(!sizeof(T), "mem_vars is not specialized"); };

template <typename T, typename M>
struct mem_refl {
  M T::*mem_ptr;
  std::string_view name;
};

template <typename T, typename M>
mem_refl(M T::*, std::string_view) -> mem_refl<T, M>;

template <typename T, typename... M>
constexpr std::tuple<mem_refl<T, M>...> make_reflect(mem_refl<T, M>... m) {
  // todo: static asssert that all the fields have been specified
  return {m...};
}

struct foo {
  std::string a;
  int b;
};

template <>
constexpr auto mem_vars<foo> = make_reflect({&foo::a, "a"} /*, mem_refl{&foo::b, "b"}*/);

This will give a deduction/substitution error:
serialization.cpp|51 col 44| error: no matching function for call to ‘make_reflect(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
||    51 | constexpr auto mem_vars<foo> = make_reflect({&foo::a, "a"} /*, mem_refl{&foo::b, "b"}*/);
||       |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
serialization.cpp|40 col 41| note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class ... M> constexpr std::tuple<mem_refl<T, M>...> make_reflect(mem_refl<T, M>...)’
||    40 | constexpr std::tuple<mem_refl<T, M>...> make_reflect(mem_refl<T, M>... m) {
||       |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
serialization.cpp|40 col 41| note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
serialization.cpp|51 col 44| note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’
||    51 | constexpr auto mem_vars<foo> = make_reflect({&foo::a, "a"} /*, mem_refl{&foo::b, "b"}*/);
||       |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

If I explicityly specify T as it asks, I get another error, which makes no sense to me
serialization.cpp|51 col 49| error: too many arguments to function ‘constexpr std::tuple<mem_refl<T, M>...> make_reflect(mem_refl<T, M>...) [with T = foo; M = {}]’
||    51 | constexpr auto mem_vars<foo> = make_reflect<foo>({&foo::a, "a"} /*, mem_refl{&foo::b, "b"}*/);
||       |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
serialization.cpp|40 col 41| note: declared here
||    40 | constexpr std::tuple<mem_refl<T, M>...> make_reflect(mem_refl<T, M>... m) {
||       |                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~

I am not sure if it doesn't work or not supposed to work at all. But when the name lookup happens, I figure, there's only one make_reflect function template, which can only have mem_refl as an argument.
I would understand if the compiler couldn't infer mem_relf from the brace-enclosed initializer list, but I'm not sure that the error implies it.  The deduction guide kicks in if I write make_reflect(mem_refl{&foo::a, "a"}), so I figure the problem lies somewhere in the order of deduction/substitution.

{..} has no type, avoiding type deduction (but exception for initializer_list and C-array).

@Jarod42 "avoiding" as in "skipping" or as in "failing with error"? Because the error also mentions substitution. Hence the confusion. If it just skipped it, the substitution {} -> mem_refl{} would work because of the deduction guide. But it does not.

@Jarod42 "has no type" -> no type candidate for substitution?

It is simply how the language is specified. Parameter/argument pairs in which the argument is a braced-enclosed initializer list are non-deduced contexts and aren't used to deduce any template arguments, neither T, nor M (which you didn't give a value in the modified version).

If you wanted to specify deduction rules for these kind of arguments, it would quickly become difficult to find a good specification covering all scenarios because you have multiple expressions that should be matched against one type, potentially involving some kind of recursive matching against constructors. Sure, you could probably find rules for aggregate classes with that simple form of class template and function parameter, but making it deducible only in special cases would only make the language even more complex and difficult to understand.

@SergeyKolesnik: decltype({42, 23}); // Error Demo as there are no type.

@user17732522 I'm not convinced though, because (here) the compiler doesn't have to deduce the "type" of an argument, it has to deduce the "specialization" of a template, which is known. So, I imagine, that in cases where a parameter is a type, no deduction is possible, like Jarod has demonstrated. But in case of a set of overloaded function with template class parameters, it might just: 1. try each candidate using deduction guides, 2. report ambiguous call is several found. I fail to see how this would make language more complicated, than convenient: one would be able to use simpler syntax

@SergeyKolesnik That would also only be a special case for a function parameter of the form Tmpl<T1,...,Tn> where each of the Ti are distinct template arguments. However, such a special case already exists for alias templates, so it might not be out-of-the question. In any case, this relies on deduction guides, which weren't a concept in C++11 when the syntax was introduced, The meaning of the syntax can't be changed now, because it would break old programs relying on the non-deduced context.

What would be possible is to simply introduce another syntax, e.g. the common CTAD syntax of a template-name without template argument list, for function parameters. At least for abbreviated function templates that should work out. I would have to look at the relevant papers for reasons that this syntax wasn't added with the abbreviated templates for C++20. With normal function templates it would be difficult to find a good syntax that is explicit in the template parameters.

@user17732522 only be a special case - I think such a case could be quite "general" in fact, since it seems like a thing desired by many people. Usually as means to write simpler code, like foo({.a = "oceanic", .b = 815}) - which is quite handy and works with non-template functions.

@SergeyKolesnik Now that specific form using designated initializers can't be handled by deduction guides. They can't encode the names of the members. So if you want to support that syntax CTAD is not a solution and you would instead be back to special rules for aggregates. I guess my point is that if you want your suggestion to work you need to 1. make sure the behavior of old code doesn't change, i.e. a non-deduced context musn't become deduced, and 2. make sure that the new parameter syntax that you need to introduce has consistent desirable deduction behavior in all scenarios.

@SergeyKolesnik: You might look at overload reolution which is already complex to have "natural" behavior. With your alternative way, we won't be able to use ADL.

@Jarod42 what I suggested is not to introduce a new type for {int(), string()}: so every template <typename T> void foo(T) would be omitted for the same reasons. However template <typename T> void foo(known_set<T>) will be considered, and each s in known_set (set of defined templates) will considered as if s{int(), string()} deduction guide was used. I can't say it will not break the pre C++ code, I just say that I don't see how (I'm not sure I expressed my idea clearly though)

@SergeyKolesnik It breaks old code, because users could rely on braces disabling deduction. For example a common pattern is std::max(x, {y}) in order to get the maximum of two variables with different types, coercing y to the type of x. If you now implement your suggestions, this would become a deduction failure, because x and y would deduce different types for the single template parameter. You would at least need to specify that the new rules are used only if template argument deduction would otherwise fail. But then you also need to consider overloads. It is just all non-trivial.

@user17732522 I frankly didn't intend to suggest a new syntax in the question, I was curious why it is not possible currently. Your and Jarod42's answers are very comprehensive and more than enough.

@user17732522 I might consider looking into the std::max example, since I am not entirely convinced that my suggestion would break the code (it might, I'm not sure), since I (as I stated above) {y} will still be an undeduced context. So for std::max<T>(T, T), everything stays the same. For std::max<T>(foo<T>, foo<T>), where foo<T> x, y the invocation foo(x, {y}) will not consider max<T>(T, T) in the set, but will include max<T>(foo<T>, foo<T>), and if foo<T>{foo<T>}, than the overload will be selected. But if there's bar(foo<T>), will be ambiguous call, just like it is now(?)
